# STRTOK not supporting for question mark(?) as a delimiter in [snowflake]

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a business requirement that has a VARCHAR column in [snowflake] with multiple delimiters . I am using STRTOK function available in snowflake for getting the requested part based on multiple delimiters like @,{,<,?.. One of the delimiter is question mark(?) but snowflake is not supporting ? as a delimiter in STRTOK function. Please can any one suggest any other options for this . You can refer below example .

```
WITH tbl
  AS (select t.column1 mycol from values
('discount-offer&kclickid=9b1946f1-1239-12gh-1cc8-a20dfg2f1dcv'),
('penny-offer？AID=10854181&PID=8330848&CID=4918330&affpat=1'),
('abc^123'),
('kxncjdhc#kjhcjk'),
('ndcjdnjd%^k&dh'),
('jsndj*') t )
SELECT mycol,
strtok(mycol,' !"#$%&()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~"',1)
FROM tbl
```

Comment: The question mark in your `Values` string is not a question mark. It is a `？` "Full Width Question Mark" character. Use that in your strtok and it will start working. Here's a working example: `SELECT strtok('penny-offer？AID=10854181&PID=8330848&CID=4918330&affpat=1','？',1) `

Comment: Thanks for responding to my question. This is working when we use one delimeter(?) in STRTOK(). With multiple delimiters, it is not showing up the result as expected. WITH tbl AS (select t.column1 mycol from values('discount-offer&kclickid=9b1946f1-1239-12gh-1cc8-a20dfg2f1dcv'), 
             ('penny-offer？AID=10854181&PID=8330848&CID=4918330&affpat=1'), ('abc^123'),('kxncjdhc#kjhcjk'),('ndcjdnjd%^k&dh'),('jsndj*') t ) 
             SELECT mycol,strtok(mycol,'? !"#$%&()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~"',1) FROM tbl

Comment: Your delimiter parameter is still missing the Full Width Question Mark character. Try:

`WITH tbl AS (select t.column1 mycol from values('discount-offer&kclickid=9b1946f1-1239-12gh-1cc8-a20dfg2f1dcv'), ('penny-offer？AID=10854181&PID=8330848&CID=4918330&affpat=1'), ('abc^123'),('kxncjdhc#kjhcjk'),('ndcjdnjd%^k&dh'),('jsndj*') t ) SELECT mycol,strtok(mycol,'？? !"#$%&()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~"',1) FROM tbl` You can see both the difference in those two leading question marks. One is normal ASCII and the other is the Unicode Full Width version. (Tested in Snowflake just now)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response . It is working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the answer from comments to an answer for completeness:

- The problem was that the question mark in the test input was not a normal question mark, but a "full width question mark" character: `？`
- Hence the solution was adding that character to the `strtok()` function.

(thx @JNevill)